# lights not flashing off in loop function

Tags: arduino

So for a little background I am both new to Arduino and as well as to C++. I mostly deal with Javascript, so its likely I made some assumptions while programming this.

The goal of my code is to have a number of lights all flashing in sequence.
the function should turned the light on for each pin, waiting a second or so, then turning off all the pin, and then this is called again in the loop. However, in both the arduino and the online IDE, the LED flashed on but remained on.

My (incredibly generic) question is what is going wrong with my loop?

```
int NumOfOutputs = 1;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:


  if(NumOfOutputs >= 1){
    for(int i = 2; i < NumOfOutputs + 2; i++){
      pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    }
  }
}



void flashSequence1(float baseRate){
    for(int i = 2; i < NumOfOutputs + 2; i++){
      digitalWrite(i,HIGH);   
    }
    size_t: print(delay);
    delay(baseRate * 1.00);
    for(int i = 2; i < NumOfOutputs + 2; i++){
      digitalWrite(i,LOW);
    }

}


void flashSequence2(float baseRate, unsigned int repeat){

}

void flashSequence3(float baseRate, unsigned int repeat){

}

void loop() {
  float baseRate = 1.0;

  flashSequence1(baseRate);
  //flashSequence2();
  //flashSequence3();

}
```

Comment: It's probably flashing, but the LOW is so short, you can't see it.

Comment: parameter of delay is `unsigned long millis`. `size_t: print(delay);` is nonsense

Answer (score 0):

Your delay is so short. It's simple: In order to make the human eye detect that a led is flashing,  the delay between the led is on and the led is off must be greater than 10 msec. This came from my experiment with leds on Arduino.

Also, you should put a delay after led is on and a delay after led is off too.